# JSON Schema with a minimum length, unless empty/null

Tags: c#, json, schema, jsonschema

I'm creating a JSON Schema, and I'm using a definition for social security number, and I'm wondering if I can have both a minimum length AND allow it to be null in the same definition.

```
"socialSecurityField":{
"type": "string",
"minLength":9,
"maxLength": 11,
"pattern":"(^\\d{3}([ -])?)\\d{2}([ -])?)\\d{4})?"
}
```

So we have a SS field that will allow just numbers, or numbers and dashes, and no letters, but not nulls unless I get rid of the minLength.

How do I allow nulls AND minLength?

Answer (score 6):

The `type` keyword can take an array of values. This allows you to specify several types that your schema will accept.

```
{
  "type": [ "string", "null" ],
  ...
}
```

Keep the rest of the schema as is. The other keywords you have will only apply *if* the value is a string.

Comment: To clarify, `minLength` for example is only applicable if the value is a string. If not, it has no effect.